# My 'GoogleChart Pie' shows only thin slices

Tags: php, pie-chart

When I echo data to my Pie Chart only thin slices will be shown with a percentage of 1% and 0.2%. Which, obviously, is not the 100% it should show.  I have tried all kind of combinations but w/o any luck.
See the example here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2j8X.jpg

My code:

```
<?php
  include "config.php";
           
  $query = "SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Success = '1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Successes, COUNT(CASE WHEN Success = '0' AND EndTime > '1970-01-01 00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Failures, COUNT(CASE WHEN Success = '0' AND EndTime = '1970-01-01 00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) As Incompletes, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM DiskOperationLog";

 $result = mysqli_query($dbhandle, $query);  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
  <title>WipeDrive Dashboard</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
</head>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>  
           <script type="text/javascript">  
           google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});  
           google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);  
           function drawChart()  
           {  
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
                   ['Success', 'Fail'],
                                             
                          <?php  
                         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {   
                         echo "['Successes', '$row[0]'], ['Failures', '$row[1]']";
                           }  
                           ?>  
          
                     ]);  
                var options = {  
                      title: 'Wipe Results',
                      pieSliceText: 'value-and-percentage',
                      slices: {0: {color: '#1bbd0e'}, 1:{color: '#ff3333'}}, 
                      is3D:true,  
                     };  

                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));  
                chart.draw(data, options);  
           }  
           </script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div style="width:900px;">  
                <h3 align="left">WipeDrive Dashboard</h3>  
                <br />  
                <div id="piechart" style="width: 755px; height: 375px;"></div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

Assuming the cause is in the 'echo' line I have tried all I could think off in here.

The ones below give the right chart, but the name and value are the same, which are both the amount.
So if the values are 179 and 33, the pie is divided correctly but instead of having "Successes" and "Failures" as names the numbers (179 & 33) are there.

```
echo "['".$row["Successes"]."', ".$row[0]."],";
echo "['".$row["Failures"]."', ".$row[1]."],";
```

If I echo below, the chart does show 100% and it looks like it is working. So I guess adding the 2nd value is the issue here and I miss an important step/function/option.

```
echo "['Successes', '$row[0]']";
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe the problem comes from your SQL query. What are the four values you get? I suspect that `Total` is way bigger than `Successes + Failures`.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, The total would be 227 (Successes 181, Failures 33, incompletes 10). So even if it picks up all, it should be much more than 1%. Also if I take either Successes or Failures it will show 100% with a value of either 181 or 33.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference), you are misusing `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable`.

Besides, you don't need to use a loop since you always have exactly one row.

The following should initialize your `data` variable correctly:

```
<?php $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); ?>
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  [
    {label: 'Outcome', type: 'string'},
    {label: 'Count', type: 'number'},
  ],
  ['Success', parseInt('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')],
  ['Fail', parseInt('<?php echo $row[1]; ?>')]
]);
```

If short open tags are activated, you may use `<?= $row[0] ?>` instead of `<?php echo $row[0]; ?>`.

Comment: If I am using the string 1:1 it will show no data at all. 
Removing the 'label' lines, nothing will happen either. But if I add `[success', 'failed']` above `<?php echo $row[0]; ?>` it will bring me back with the root of this cause.

`['Succes', 'fail'],
  ['Success', '<?php echo $row[0]; ?>'],
  ['Fail', '<?php echo $row[1]; ?>'],`

Comment: Solved it, by adding parseInt in the script of @FabianPijcke

`<?php $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); ?>

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

  [

    {label: 'Success', type: 'string'},
    {label: 'Fail', type: 'number'},

  ],

  ['Successes', parseInt('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')],

  ['Failures', parseInt('<?php echo $row[1]; ?>')],

  ]);`
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear you got things sorted out! :-) Have a nice day

Comment: I updated my answer according to your comment. Feel free to mark my answer as correct so that StackOverflow members know that they don't need to focus on this question anymore :-)

Comment: Oh actually I think it is because Javascript sees '42' as a string. So you can probably just do `['Success', <?php echo $row[0] ?>],` (no apostrophes around the PHP tags). Can you please tell me if this works? So that we have the best answer possible? Thank you,